# Under what circumstances does row reducing an integer matrix yield another integer matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, integers, gaussian-elimination

If I start with a matrix of all integers, and put it in row reduced echelon form, in general I will not get a matrix of all integers. Under what circumstances does the resulting matrix have all integers?

Comment: I think that you'll end up with a matrix of integers if and only if the matrix is [unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks, thats what i was looking for - but what if the matrix isnt square?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : If the entries are integers, you can ALWAYS get a fully reduced form in which all entries are integers. See my answer below.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I thought the definition of row reduced echelon form required all the pivots to be 1 (otherwise how is it going to be unique?).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Even in the case of square matrices, there are rref forms with integer entries which are not invertible (small example: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$).

Comment: @DanielSchepler : ok, in that case you can make it all integers until the very last step.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$If all ratios of entries to other entries in the same row are rational numbers, as in fact they are if all entries are integers, then you can use row operations to get a fully reduced matrix in which all entries are integers.
\begin{align}
& \begin{bmatrix} 12 & -4 & 5 & -6 \\ 15 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & -3 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
& \qquad \text{You have $\lcm(12,15) = 60$ and $\lcm(12,2)=12$, so do this:} \\
& \qquad \text{2nd row } \longleftarrow (4\times\text{2nd}) + (-5\times \text{1st}) \\
& \qquad \text{3rd } \longleftarrow (6\times\text{3rd}) + (-1\times\text{1st}) \\[10pt]
& \begin{bmatrix} 12 & -4 & 5 & -6 \\ 0 & 32 & -17 & 34 \\ 0 & 4 & -23 & 12 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
By using LCMs, you keep the entries as integers.

But suppose somehow you get a row of rational numbers, like this:
$$
\begin{array}{rrrr}
\dfrac{88}{51} & \dfrac{19}{68} & \dfrac 7 {12} & \dfrac{8}{15}
\end{array}
$$
We have $\lcm(51,68,12,15) = 1020.$

One way to find this is via prime factorizations:
$$
\begin{align}
51 & = 3\times17\\
68 & = 2\times2\times17\\
12 & = 2\times2\times3\\
15 & = 3\times5
\end{align}
$$
The LCM is the smallest number divisible by $3,$ by $2\times2,$ by $17,$ and by $5,$ thus $2\times2\times3\times5\times17 = 1020.$

The elementary row operation to apply now is multiplication of every member of the row by $1020.$

Do not do it like this: $\displaystyle 1020\times \frac{88}{51} = \frac{89760}{51}.$ Instead, cancel before multiplying:$\require{cancel}$
$$
1020\times \frac{88}{51} = (20\times \cancel{51})\times\frac{88}{\cancel{51}} = 1760,
$$
and similarly in every case the denominator cancels out completely, and you get
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
1760 & 285 & 595 & 544
\end{array}
$$
Every entry is an integer.

If you define fully reduced form that requires every pivot element to be $1,$ then you'll still need to divide each row by the leading entry and you won't get all integers. So this doesn't answer your question in that case. I'm inclined to let that division wait until the last step.

Comment: This algorithm for finding the LCM is efficient only when the prime factorizations can be found efficiently. There are other elementary algorithms for it that remain efficient even when that cannot be done, but it would take some space to describe those.

Comment: In fact, since the Euclidean algorithm for calculating the GCD can be expressed in terms of invertible row operations, you can do the reduction without ever involving rational numbers.  e.g. if the first column is $(16, 10, 5)$, then first take the gcd of 16 and 10 by subtracting second row from first row -> first column $(6, 10, 5)$.  Then swap first and second rows -> first column $(10, 6, 5)$.  Then subtract the second row from the first row, etc. until eventually you get $(2,0,5)$ as first column.  Then, take the gcd of 2 and 5 until you get first column $(1,0,0)$.  Repeat for other cols.

Comment: @DanielSchepler : As I said, "By using LCMs, you keep the entries as integers." $\qquad$

Comment: When I refer to row reduced echelon form i mean pivot elements are all 1, and elements above pivots are zero

Comment: OK, I guess I was thinking more in terms of trying to use only unimodular row operations.  One possible benefit of this: "2nd row $\longleftarrow (4 \times \mathrm{2nd}) + (-5 \times \mathrm{1st})$" doesn't preserve the "row space" of the matrix as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^4$ whereas my operations do.